# Mapping a key based on the device the key is on? (Linux)

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, keymapping

I own a [Razer Naga Mouse](http://gamingweapons.com/image/razer/naga-mouse/razer-naga-00.jpg), essentaly it has a small numpad on the side of it. I want to remap these keys to different unused keys or to bash commands. I can do this easily by using xev to grab the keycode (for instance the "1" on the mouse is keycode 87) and then I can use xmodmap to bind the keycode to a different key.

However the numpad on my keyboard will also inherit this as the keycode is the same, what I noticed though is that the "serial" is different.

For instance here is the output from xev when pressing the "1" button on my mouse numpad.

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
root 0x1ae, subw 0x0, time 2179878, (170,-2), root:(198,345),
state 0x0, keycode 87 (keysym 0xff9c, KP_End), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
root 0x1ae, subw 0x0, time 2179966, (170,-2), root:(198,345),
state 0x0, keycode 87 (keysym 0xff9c, KP_End), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

and here is the output when pressing "1" on my keyboards numpad

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
root 0x1ae, subw 0x0, time 2180261, (170,-2), root:(198,345),
state 0x0, keycode 87 (keysym 0xff9c, KP_End), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
root 0x1ae, subw 0x0, time 2180341, (170,-2), root:(198,345),
state 0x0, keycode 87 (keysym 0xff9c, KP_End), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Is there anyway I could map the keys on my mouse based on this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `xmodmap`, try using [`setxkbmap`](http://man.cx/setxkbmap%281%29) and [`xkbcomp`](http://man.cx/xkbcomp). The `xkbcomp` command lets you specify an input device ID (using the `-i` option).

To get a list of device IDs run `xinput --list`. (FWIW, my Razer Salmosa was clearly labeled as "Razer Razer Salmosa".)

Here's how I converted my USB keyboard (ID 16) to use the German key mapping, while keeping my laptop keyboard on a US mapping:

```
setxkbmap de -print | xkbcomp - -i 16 $DISPLAY
```

I don't really know how to set up `xkb` mappings, but I found a [tutorial that looks pretty good](http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/).

Answer (score 1):

Ok Solved. Follow instructions on this wiki https://github.com/graph/Razer-Naga-HotKey/wiki/How-to-get-Razer-Naga-HotKeying-Working-on-Debian

Comment: I got linux code for my system, and stuck now. I dont see init_module() function anywhere in the /drivers/hid/usbhid :(

Comment: I found /dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_Razer_Naga-event-kbd and doing a hexdump on this seems like something I can right a program to parse. Going this route interpretation by X for razer naga will need to be disabled.

Comment: I didn't realize the the question is almost a year old... hopefully my answer can help you, though :)

Comment: hi Dan, I cant comment on your post, but I found a way to disable x from reading the razer keyboard "xinput set-int-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 8 0". And the /dev/... is still active which is good, it means I can convert those.

I have seen the re-mapping stuff you posted, but I couldn't figure out how to use it to my advantage. I tried remapping to a language I dont use where the keyboard layout "0-9" buttons are something I will never use lol. But pressing buttons on razer mouse still prints 1,2,3 etc...

And yes I'm still interested thanks for helping, but I dont know about OP lol

Comment: also setxkbmap & xkbcomp mess up the layout for my keyboard. Also XFCE keyboard layout program crashes when I use those commands

Comment: OK, that's cool if you can just use the raw device (I wouldn't worry about getting the `xkb` stuff set up).

Comment: The udev rule below works when bInterfaceProtocol is omitted. But I need a way to distinguish the keyboard from the mouse.


ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1532", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0015",  MODE="0644", SYMLINK+="naga_keyboard"

Comment: ...I'm not really sure what to do. You should open a new question.

Comment: ok its all solved I got the buttons hot keyed, can run any program from them and do what ever :) :). Now I just need a place to put all the code to share with others, but now feeling kinda lazy.

Comment: neither the user nor the wiki page exists

Comment: In case someone cares, that much time after, the reason `setxkbmap` messes up the main keyboard is you have to give it the device id you want to update, otherwise it will change the settings for the root keyboard.